# vector throwing a "Access violation reading location" exception. C++. VS 2012

Tags: c++, exception, vector, visual-studio-2012

the vector in question is declared like this:

```
vector<int> lowerList;
```

the vector is cleared if it is not empty using:

```
if(!lowerList.empty()){
    lowerList.clear();
}
```

the vector is then filled with between 0 and 8 numbers using:

```
lowerList.push_back();
```

one of the vectors elements is selected at random and moved to using:

```
if(!lowerList.empty()){

    int element = rand()%lowerList.size();

    int lowerIndex = lowerList.at(element);

    MoveTo(lowerIndex, currentX, currentZ);
}
```

and the onlyother time the vector is accessed is like this:

```
if(lowerList.empty()){
    return true;
}else
    return false;
```

i am getting a runtime error which says:

Unhandled exception at 0x00C702C8 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0870249C.

but from what i can see there isnt anything wrong with the way i access my vector.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `MoveTo()`? Also, do you have multiple threads?

Comment: BTW, `return lowerList.empty()`.

Comment: Which line is it breaking on?  Have you used the debugger?

Comment: No point checking `lowerList.empty()` before `lowerList.clear()`...

Comment: @ andy i dont have multiple threads.
@ juan and @Stephen yeh those amendments make sense so ive implemented them.
@ paddy im not sure ive been trying to work that out myself. but i cant find where exactly it is crashing

Comment: Did you at least check where it crashes with a debugger?

Comment: ive set breakpoints up all over the show but it is difficult as those bits of code are actually within a for loop which loops like 5000 times meaning i cant check sit and check everyline of code being worked through

Comment: Any chance your random call is returning a value one beyond your vector size?

Comment: I don't know about yours, but last I checked, when debugging, some IDEs automatically break to the debugger when a segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: Looking at the list upon a crash to see its size and what values are being passed along will rule out memory corruption and out of bounds access.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan that isnt where the issue is. ive tested that by jus8t setting the value to 0 and the exception still occurs.

Comment: Perhaps soemthing else is smashing it in memory then - tiem to set write to memeory break points to check that...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan but...how?

Comment: If you had a write off the end of an array bug elsewhere in your code that happened to hit this container's RAM, you could easily see something like this.  Watching the memory wehre the container is allocated outside of where you expect it to be modified would show you this sort of bug.  It's not an uncommon situation, but it tends to be pretty difficult to track.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan i do have an array in the code but it is initialised way before the vector. does that make a difference?

Comment: and how would i check where the the container is being modified. sorry about my noobiness.